# Can XML be generated with Groovy MarkupBuilder that has double quotes in it?

Tags: java, xml, groovy

Using this code:

```
xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder() 
xmldata = xml.Plugins(nextid: '10') {
   Target(name: 'default.auth') {
     Port(protocol: 'https') {
       mkp.yield 8080
     }
   }
}
```

Generates this output:

```
<Plugins nextid='10'>
  <Target name='default.auth'>
    <Port protocol='https'>8083</Port>
  </Target>
</Plugins>
```

But, is there a way to generate the output like this, with double-quotes?

```
<Plugins nextid="10">
  <Target name="default.auth">
    <Port protocol="https">8083</Port>
  </Target>
</Plugins>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, here's the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html#setDoubleQuotes-boolean-). `MarkupBuilder.setDoubleQuotes(true)`

And in case the link goes bad (copied from the above link, applies to Groovy 2.4.10)

---

## setDoubleQuotes

```
public void setDoubleQuotes(boolean useDoubleQuotes)
```

Sets whether the builder outputs attribute values in double quotes or single quotes.

**Parameters:**

- `useDoubleQuotes` - If this parameter is true, double quotes are used; otherwise, single quotes are.

---